# How to configure __init__ in FlaskForm to have same functionalities?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

So I want to pass a variable to a flask form, in order to do it I've decided to modify the `__init__` of `SongForm`, but when I do it the album field loses its properties in the html. Does anyone know how do i have to correct my `__init__`

Here is forms.py:

```
class SongForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Name", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=40)])
    cover = StringField("Cover", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=120)])
    content=StringField("Content", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=120)])
    release_date=DateField("Release Date", validators=[DataRequired()])
    genre=SelectField("Genre", choices=Genre.list)
    
    album = None
    
    submit = SubmitField("Upload")
    
    def __init__(self, username, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super(SongForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.album = SelectField("Album", choices=Album.get_albums(username), validate_choice=True )
        self.album.label = 'Album'
```

NB:`Album.get_albums()` is a function that executes a query and gets a list from database. So it has to receive the parameter username in the constructor.
Or if there is a better way to pass a parameter without breaking the form.

Here is routes.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user

from Codice.models import *
from Codice.database import *
from Codice.artist.forms import *

# Blueprint Configuration
artist = Blueprint('artist', __name__, static_folder='static',
                 template_folder='templates')

@artist.route('/insertsong', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def insertsong():
    form = ModifyProfileForm() # <-- don't mind this form will be removed later
    form2 = SongForm(current_user.username)
    
    return render_template('insertsong.html', form = form, form2=form2, user = current_user)
```

Here is part of insertsong.html code:

```
<div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
     {{ form2.album(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
     {{ form2.album.label(class="form-label")}} 
</div>
```

But when I execute it breaks showing this error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 303, in decorated_view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(func)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/artist/routes.py", line 28, in insertsong
    return render_template('insertsong.html', form = form, form2=form2, user = current_user)
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 148, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1291, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/home/profscrew/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 926, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/artist/templates/insertsong.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'menu.html' %}
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/templates/menu.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/templates/base.html", line 35, in top-level template code
    {% block pagebody %}{% endblock %}
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/templates/menu.html", line 86, in block 'pagebody'
    {% block content %}
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/artist/templates/insertsong.html", line 24, in block 'content'
    {{ form2.album.label(class="small mb-1")}}
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Although if `(class="")` is removed from the html code it executes but it shows up as plain text and not a SelectField

PS: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tried to set the label property (incorrectly) to the same value which you've just set in the previous line via the `label` parameter, i.e. this second line is redundant.

Anyway, here's why you are getting the error. Consider the following code:

```
def __init__(self, username, *args, **kwargs):
        
    super(SongForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.album = SelectField("Album", choices=Album.get_albums(username), validate_choice=True )
    self.album.label = 'Album' # here is your error
```

A field's label property isn't a `str` it's an instance of a Label [class](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/fields/?highlight=label#wtforms.fields.Label), which is why you're getting the `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` error.

An instance of this class is created and assigned to the label property when you pass in a value for the `label` parameter in a field's constructor e.g.

```
name = StringField("Name", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=40)])
```

If you want to change a field's label at runtime you'd do something like the following:

```
# within the form class
self.album.label = Label(self.album.id, 'Album Name')

# or on a form instance
form2.album.label = Label(form2.album.id, 'Album Name')
```

Personally, I wouldn't have any database calls in a form's definition, I'd set the choices at runtime. e.g.

```
class SongForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Name", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=40)])
    cover = StringField("Cover", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=120)])
    content = StringField("Content", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=120)])
    release_date = DateField("Release Date", validators=[DataRequired()])
    genre = SelectField("Genre")
    album = SelectField("Album", validate_choice=True)


@artist.route('/insertsong', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def insertsong():
    form = ModifyProfileForm() # <-- don't mind this form will be removed later
    
    form2 = SongForm()
    
    # Set your choices at runtime
    form2.genre.choices = Genre.list
    form2.album.choices = Album.get_albums(username)
    
    return render_template('insertsong.html', form = form, form2=form2, user = current_user)
```